# OracleBulkCopy error: '0' is not a valid value for 'Interval'

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following code

```
    using (OracleConnection srcConn = new OracleConnection())
    using (OracleConnection destConn = new OracleConnection())
    {
      srcConn.ConnectionString = AppInfo.SrcConnStr;
      srcConn.Open();
      destConn.ConnectionString = AppInfo.DestConnStr;
      destConn.Open();

      using (OracleCommand destCmd = new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'", destConn))
      using (OracleCommand srcCmd = new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'", srcConn))
      {

        // Non-query
        srcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        destCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (Timing) { ut.TimeIt(stopwatch, "Get Connection and Command"); }

        srcCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        destCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        srcCmd.CommandText = "select * from table_name";
        rd = srcCmd.ExecuteReader();
        rd.FetchSize = rd.RowSize * AppInfo.BatchSize; }

        OracleBulkCopy copy = new OracleBulkCopy(destConn);
        copy.DestinationTableName = DestTable;
        copy.BatchSize = AppInfo.BatchSize;
        copy.NotifyAfter = AppInfo.BatchSize;
        copy.OracleRowsCopied += new OracleRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnOracleRowsCopied);
        copy.BulkCopyTimeout = AppInfo.CommandTimeOut;
        copy.WriteToServer(rd);

      }
    }
```

When it got to copy.WriteToServer(rd); it gives the following error

```
 System.ArgumentException was caught
 Message='0' is not a valid value for 'Interval'. 'Interval' must be greater than 0.
 Source=System
 StackTrace:
   at System.Timers.Timer.set_Interval(Double value)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.PerformBulkCopy()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.WriteDataSourceToServer()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
```

My question is, How do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be setting `CommandTimeout`s to zero.  Try a reasonable number.  I think this is specified in seconds.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. You are right. copy.BulkCopyTimeout is set to 0, which is the cause of this error. Setting it to a non-zero number works.